# Cisco IPS - At what temperature will the IPS halt?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, intrusion-prevention

We have an IPS module inside a Cisco ASA. It is an SSM-10. Looking in the show tech of the IPSM I see this line:

`Halt Device on Over Temp   : 1`

I believe that means the system will halt when the temperature gets too hot. What is considered too hot?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

> What is considered too hot?

The environmental specs (including operating temperature) are listed on the [data sheet for the module](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps6032/ps6094/ps6120/ps6823/product_data_sheet0900aecd80402e4f_ps6120_Products_Data_Sheet.html).

In this case, it appears that the operating temperature range is 32 to 104ºF (0º to 40ºC).